# How does proximality relates to p- limit?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, ramsey-theory

Please help me to solve a problem given in the survey [Minimal Idempotents and Ergodic Ramsey theory by Vitaly Bergelson](https://people.math.osu.edu/bergelson.1/vbkatsiveli20march03.pdf)(Exercise 15(iii), page  23), which is

**Problem:** Prove that if $x_1,x_2$ are proximal points in a topological system $(X,T)$($X$ is compact and $T$ is continuous), then there exists $p\in \beta\mathbb{N}$ such that $p-lim_{n\in \mathbb{N}}T^nx_1=p-lim_{n\in \mathbb{N}}T^nx_2.$

**Definition(Proximal point):** Given a dynamical system $(X,T),x_1,x_2\in X$ is called proximal if there exists a sequence $n_k\rightarrow \infty$ such that $d(T^{n_k}x_1,T^{n_k}x_2)\rightarrow 0.$

**Definition(p-limit):** Given an ultrafilter $p\in \beta \mathbb{N}$ and a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in a topological space $X$, one writes $p-lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=y$ if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $y$, one has $\{n:x_n\in U\}\in p.$

Comment: $T^{n_k}x_1$ is a sequence in a compact space, thus there is some accumulation point $y$ that is the limit of some sub-sequence with powers/indices $n_{k_i}$, and $T^{n_{k_i}}x_2$ has the same limit. Now translate into the language of ultra-filters.

Comment: @LutzL Given a sequence $\{n_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, how can you say that there exists $p\in\beta\mathbb{N}$ such that $\{n_k:k\geq k_0\} \in p$ for all $k_0\in \mathbb{N}$? This is the fact I need to translate your argument in the language of ultrafilter.

Comment: Is there any restriction on the ultrafilters above the defining properties? Say that they are co-finite? Why not take the set of these sequences and extend to an UF?

Comment: @LutzL Thanks! You're right. We can extend it to an ultrafilter as the collection satisfy the finite intersection property.

Comment: In NSA, which in some formulations is defined via UF, the statement is just that there is some inf-large $n$ with $T^nx_1\approx T^nx_2$, and because of compactness, there is some $y=st(T^nx_1)=°(T^nx_1)$ and then $T^nx_2$ belongs to the same fluffy flake of $y$ of infinitesimally close points, so that also $y=st(T^nx_2)$.